Increment to next List object inside for loop
If I have a for loop like this:

List<Person> people;

for (Person person : people) {
    ...
}

Is it possible to increment to the next person inside the for loop in the same way I could have:
List<Person> people;

for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    Person person = people.get(i);
    i++;
    people.get(i);
}


Your example is confusing. What are you actually trying to achieve?

You could manually track the index by initializing a counter outside the enhanced for loop, and then incremented it within the loop to track the current index. Then you could use people[index+1] to grab the next entry. I don't believe there is any built in functionality for this in enhanced loops.

Are you planning to do anything with either or both of those Person objects?  Are you hoping to use the first Person object but ignore every other one?  Right now you're just storing one to a variable but not doing anything with it, so it's unclear what your intent is.

The enhanced for loop unconditionally iterates over every element in a collection. You can work around this, for example:
Instead of:
for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if (skipThis(...))
        i++;
    Person person = people.get(i);
    processPerson();
}

You can do:
for (Person person : people) {
    if (!skipThis(...)) {
        process(person);
    }
}


When I want to do something more complicated than a for-each loop allows, I use a classic iterator loop using iterator() or listIterator() (depending on whether I need the index):
for (Iterator<E> i = people.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Person person = i.next();
    if (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
    }
}

It's not as succinct as a for-each loop, but I feel it does a better job of matching the iteration abstraction than an index-based for-loop.

No, the enhanced for loop (also known as for-each loop) does not track an index number.
You could add code to track the index.  But at that point you might as well use the conventional for loop. The for-each loop is meant to be a convenience in those common situations where you have no need for an index.
The equivalent of this:
List<Person> people = … ;

for ( Person person : people ) {
    System.out.println( person ) ;
}

… is the conventional for loop:
List<Person> people = …

for ( int index = 0 ; index < people.length ; index ++ ) {
    Person person = people.get( index );
    System.out.println( person ) ;
}

Your IDE will likely be able to convert back and forth for your convenience.
See The Java Tutorials by Oracle.
